# Emmet/VSCode auto correct not correcting CSS correctly suddenly ("wid" auto corrects to "widows" instead of "width" for e.g)

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I've been having this issue for the last couple of weeks or so. I've not installed any new extensions or changed any themes as far as I know.

My SCSS auto-correct has been acting funky, here are some examples.

Previously, typing out `wid` and then hitting `tab` would auto fill to `width`, now, it auto-fills to `widows`.

Also, `margin-bo` then hitting `tab` would auto fill to `margin-bottom`, now, it auto-fills to `margin-block`.

Very simple examples but it are so frustrating and really slows down my workflow.

Also, I turned off the setting in my VSCode settings to stop CSS from putting a `;` at the end of lines automatically, although, it still puts them.

Does anybody know what is going on?